# Entity Framework code-first to existing database using commandline

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm wondering if it's possible to generate the POCO classes from an existing database from the command line.

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
Scaffold $Connection$ Table1 Table2 Table3
```

Comment: Me too! :-) Hope someone will have an answer here....